# What does sparc_do_fork() exactly do?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I tried to find out the functionality of this function but I couldn't..  It is defined in Linux/arch/sparc/kernel/process_32.c Thanks

```
asmlinkage int sparc_do_fork(unsigned long clone_flags,
                             unsigned long stack_start,
                             struct pt_regs *regs,
                             unsigned long stack_size)
{
    unsigned long parent_tid_ptr, child_tid_ptr;
    unsigned long orig_i1 = regs->u_regs[UREG_I1];
    long ret;

    parent_tid_ptr = regs->u_regs[UREG_I2];
    child_tid_ptr = regs->u_regs[UREG_I4];

    ret = do_fork(clone_flags, stack_start, stack_size,
        (int __user *) parent_tid_ptr,
        (int __user *) child_tid_ptr);

    /* If we get an error and potentially restart the system
     * call, we're screwed because copy_thread() clobbered
     * the parent's %o1.  So detect that case and restore it
     * here.
     */
    if ((unsigned long)ret >= -ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK)
        regs->u_regs[UREG_I1] = orig_i1;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be right there in the source code.

It's a wrapper around the regular Linux `do_fork()` call, one which saves and restores data (specifically, `regs->u_regs[UREG_I1]`, which equates to the SPARC output register 1) that would otherwise be corrupted under certain circumstances:

```
/* If we get an error and potentially restart the system
     * call, we're screwed because copy_thread() clobbered
     * the parent's %o1.  So detect that case and restore it
     * here.
     */
```

It does this with:

```
unsigned long orig_i1 = regs->u_regs[UREG_I1];      // Save it.

ret = do_fork(...);

if ((unsigned long)ret >= -ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK)   // It may be corrupt
    regs->u_regs[UREG_I1] = orig_i1;                //   so restore it.
```